# Problem with citation of a reference

Tags: citing, overleaf

I am using Overleaf. I used `\begin{thebibliography}` for making references. Normally, when I want to cite somewhere in the text, I'm using `~\cite{}`. Whenever I was using `~\cite{}` a menu of the name of references appeared and I could choose the one that I wanted.  Then I wanted to make separate files for each section, so I made some `.tex`-files for each section and I managed them in a main file. After that, whenever I try to cite a reference after writing `~\cite{}` the menu of the name of references doesn't appear to choose.

Could you please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the webpage? If you're still having problems, you can contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL so that the Support can have a look at your code and files setup.

Comment: Refreshing didn't solve the problem

Comment: The list of the refs is an editor feature not a LaTeX feature. This means, if the editor doesnt support this for splitted documents, this cant be solved. Furthermore, I would recommend not to put chapters into separate documents unless the chapter is finished. But that's a question of personal taste.